# having the full field object instead of it's ID in django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin

with these two models TblPhoto

```
class TblPhoto(models.Model):
    #path = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    type = models.ForeignKey('TblPhotoTypes', models.DO_NOTHING, blank=True, null=True)
    path = models.ImageField(upload_to='images')

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_photo'
        verbose_name = "Photo"
        verbose_name_plural = "Photos"
```

and TblCustomer

```
class TblCustomer(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    token = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    firebase_token = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True, null=True)
    registration_date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    last_login_date = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    about = models.TextField(max_length=128, blank=True, null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(blank=True, null=True)
    photo = models.ForeignKey(TblPhoto, models.DO_NOTHING)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)+' : '+self.name

    class Meta:
        managed = False
        db_table = 'tbl_customer'
        verbose_name = "Customer"
        verbose_name_plural = "Customers"
```

the api response is...

```
{
    "response_status": {
        "code": 200,
        "internalMessage": "",
        "message": ""
    },
    "user": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "deya",
        "email": "gmail@gmail.com",
        "password": "",
        "token": null,
        "firebase_token": null,
        "registration_date": null,
        "last_login_date": null,
        "about": "hello, i'm Deya !",
        "active": true,
        "photo_id": 4
    }
}
```

notice the field photo_id, how can I alter the TblCustomer model to show the photo object instead of the photo id?

> Disclaimer : I can do this easily out of the model, but I want it to be in the
>   model class.

this is how I do it now... to get the additional `photo_url` key but I want to do it from the model....

```
class CustomerProfileView(BaseView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        requestBody = json.loads(request.body)
        id = requestBody["id"]
        try:
            user = TblCustomer.objects.values().get(id=id)
            photo = TblPhoto.objects.values().get(id=user["photo_id"])
            user["photo_url"] = request.scheme+"://"+request.get_host()+"/media/"+photo["path"]
            self.responseDict["user"] = user
        except Exception as e:
            return Helpers().statusCode(404,e)
        return JsonResponse(self.responseDict)
```

Comment: Where is the code that creates the api response.

Comment: I have edited the question, and added this part.